# Oracle 11g - "DEFAULT ON NULL"?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, null, default, default-value

I am running Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production, I am trying to find an equivalent to 12c's "DEFAULT ON NULL" for a table. Basically I have to create a table where the requirement is than whenever someone intentionally or inadvertently passes a NULL value, it is replaced with a DEFAULT value (in this case a NUMBER type equal to 1). Is there any easy way to do this in 11g? I know I could do a trigger on the table, but I would have to put in logic for every single column, and that seems ridiculous.

My table definition currently looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE
(
    FLAG   NUMBER(1)   DEFAULT 0
)
```

If I explicitly pass in null it WILL get stored. In that situation I was expecting the default value to be placed instead.

Comment: Null is a perfectly valid value.  Default is when a value is not supplied.  You could write a "before insert" trigger maybe?

Comment: In 11g, I'm afraid there is no native way to get it done. If you do not want to go with triggers, you can create a view. Either way you will have to write some logic for every column as you would write `default on null` for every column, only it'll be a tad longer.

Comment: I could absolutely do that. Actually I already did, I am doing COALESCE(:new.FLAG, 0) and that seems to work, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution in 11g. It seems weird that something so simple is made this complicated.

Comment: "It seems weird that something so simple is made this complicated."


Welcome to Oracle

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple 'DEFAULT' behavior for columns and don't provide anything when inserting.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id NUMBER(8.0) NOT NULL,
col1 NUMBER(8.0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 10,
col2 NUMBER(8.0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 20,
PRIMARY KEY (id);
);

INSERT INTO table1 (id) values (123); //will result in creating a row with default values.
```

Also if you're using some kind of ORM you can use dynamic insert and dynamic update options. This way if you don't provide values on insert they will be set to defaults;
and on update the unchanged values will not be included into query.

This is how you can bypass explicit null values in query and defaults will apply.